# Print barcode (3 of 9) in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, barcode-printing

I want to be able to print barcodes (with the 3 of 9 font) using the string text in a Silverlight page. Is there any simple way to do it? Or should I be using a library like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BarcodeLibrary.aspx. 
Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: I don't think a barcode font is the right choice for printing barcodes

Comment: @BoltClock So you suggest to use library and generate barcode image instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate 3 of 9 barcodes using graphic elements, but a font is easiest as the pattern for barcodes is quite tedious to replicate (I know as I generated several barcode fonts).

Try one of my barcode fonts here: http://fontstruct.com/fontstructors/hal9000lives

If you do want to try making it with UI elements, the 3 of 9 pattern is shown here:
 http://www.adams1.com/39code.html

Comment: Thanks i'll be using fonts to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to print a barcode is using a barcode font.